# Doctrine 2.2 - do i must always include all classes

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have these two classes:

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="news") */

    class News {
        /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
        protected $id;

        /** @Column(type="string", length=100) */
        protected $title;

        /** @Column(type="text") */
        protected $content;

        /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="news") */   
        protected $author;
    }
```

and

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="users") */
class User {
    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=20, unique=TRUE) */
    protected $login;

    /** @Column(type="string",length=100, unique=TRUE) */
    protected $email;

    /** @Column(type="string",length=24) */
    protected $password;

    /** @OneToOne(targetEntity="Rank", mappedBy="user") */
    protected $rank;    
}
```

Is there any way to skip including `User` and `Rank` (used in `User`) classes (which are in separate files) if I want only do this code:

```
$result = $em->createQuery("SELECT n.title FROM News n WHERE id = 15")->getResult();
```

I'm asking, because it's strange to add those classes even if I don't need them in my query...

Comment: What do you mean "you don't use it in your query"?
I any query of your project?
Do you incude fields that are useless (author is news and rank in user)??

Comment: I mean, that I'm getting only one field from News class (`title`) and nothing more (not in whole project, but only on one page). That's why I don't need `User` and `Rank` classes.

Comment: Then no, you cannot skip rank and user classes. News has a reference to Users and User to Rank.

Comment: Are you explicitly loading the classes with require statements?  Your class loader should be doing this for you.  In which case, classes will only be loaded when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your query above, you're only loading a scalar value from an entity, this will be translated in a single SQL query on the `News` table alone.

Doctrine might still internally load metadata for the User and Rank classes, thus triggering the class autoloader. But that's not something you should worry about: with production settings, you usually use [metadata caching](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/caching.html), thus when running your query, there shouldn't be any overhead:

```php
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache());
```

Don't use this setting on your development machine, use `ArrayCache` instead.